# Is AMD Ryzen Threadripper compatible with Tensorflow gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, amd-processor

Hi I'm evaluating the purchase of an ASROCK x399 motherboard with `AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2950x 16 Core` CPU to use 4 or 8 gpu at the same time (in parallel on different training). 
I was wondering if there were hardware incompatibilities with `nVidia 2080ti` and `tensorflow-gpu`.

I would like to avoid buying 10k of hardware that is then incompatible with the libraries.

Is there native support for this CPU? Or do I have to use open source walkthroughs that often cause problems?

Do you have feedback for me?

Comment: AMD CPU's work just fine with tensorflow, and are usually better value than Intel CPU's. Do note that tensorflow-gpu **only** works with nVidia GPU's. Other than that, make sure the CPU has enough PCIe lanes for the number of GPU's you want to connect.

Comment: Thanks, I already done PCI maths.. Workstation configuration is ok. I'm just afraid of some istruction set incompatibility between amd and nvidia driver